# Setting text color in text box C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a multi line text box which is used to display the status messages of the operations that I do in the application. I want to set separate colors for different lines in the text box. If I use the ForeColor property, it sets the color of all the text. I want to set the color of a single line. How can I do this?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) instead. You can then use the properties [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx), [SelectionLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionlength.aspx), and [SelectionColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncolor.aspx) to achieve what you want, as the easiest solution. You can also modify the RTF directly. You can actually just edit the designer code and change System.Windows.Forms.TextBox references to RichTextBox, then make some small modifications to your code.

Answer (score 2):

TextBox control doesn't support coloring of intermediate lines. use ListView instead. You can achieve a similar look-and-feel by using "Details" or "List" View mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with the built in control.

Either inherit it and create your own control, or use something like this:
[Background color of a ListBox item (winforms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms/3709452#3709452)

In there it's background color but you can same way apply different fore color.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox does not support multiple colors (or fonts or sizes). You'll have to use RichTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You need to use [Rich TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a richtextbox for this. You can specify all sorts of formatting inline with your text