# Change a ListBox Background Color

Tags: c#, listbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Background color of a ListBox item (winforms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms)

I have a ListBox, that for every coordinates I need to have different colours. ex.

```
23,34 //red background
56,78 //green background
90,2 // yellow background
```

Code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < il_kl; i++)
        {
            int il_pkt = Klastry[i].Punkty.Count;
            string color = lista_kolor[i]; 
            Brush mybrush = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(color);

            for (int j = 0; j < il_pkt; j++)
            {
                x = Klastry[i].Punkty[j].X;
                y = Klastry[i].Punkty[j].Y;

                _mn.kolekcje_wsp.Items.Add(x + " , " + y);
                _mn.kolekcje_wsp.Foreground = mybrush;

            }

        }
```

I'm using `Foreground` now, but how to change the `Background` color for every coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following and see if it works for you

Probably the only way to accomplish that is to draw the items yourself.

Set the DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed

and code something like this on the DrawItem event:

```
private void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    Graphics myCustomGraphic = e.Graphics;
    myCustomGraphic.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), e.Bounds);
    // Print text
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```