# C# Winforms ListBox Set BackColor when item meets condition

Tags: c#, winforms, collections, listbox

I have a collection that is the DataSource of a ListBox.
I'd like to enumerate the ListBox items and change the BackColor when the collection item has a certain property. The code in the for isn't working at all and i'm lost.
How would i change the BackColor is the corresponding Categorie has a certain ID ?

```
  categorien.Add(new Categorie() { ID = 0, Naam = "Blond" });
  categorien.Add(new Categorie() { ID = 1, Naam = "Donker" });
  listBox1.DataSource = categorien;
  listBox1.DisplayMember = "Naam";
  listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";

  for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++ ) {
    if (categorien.ID == someID) {
      listBox1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Gray;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

try below

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var category = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as Categorie;
    Color backColor = Color.Green;
    if (category.ID == someID)
    {
        backColor = Color.Gray;
    }

    // draw back color and text 
}
```

Comment: that didn't work but you saved me by providing the "as Category", thanks, i upvote you and publish the sollution

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more work to color specific items in a listbox. See the discussion below.

[Background color of a ListBox item (winforms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms)

Comment: i'm not struggling with the coloring but with getting the ListBox item that meets a criteria on the collection

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can't you simply do a `foreach (Categorie c in categorien) if (c.ID = someID) ...`? And the `listBox1.Items` collection is just going to contain the Categorie instances.

Comment: of course i can iterate the collection but then how do i get the corresponding ListBox item to change its BackColor ?

Comment: There is no ListBoxItem in WinForms. There is no object on which you can simply set the BackColor. Please see the discussion in the link I posted. In order to do what you want to do, you must catch the DrawItem event off the ListBox. You'll read the item index from the DrawItemEventArgs passed to that event handler. You can then get the Categorie item from from from the ListBox.Items collection, and evaluate it to determine which color to paint it.

Comment: Or use ListView instead, which does allow you to control the background color of each item simply by setting properties on the ListViewItem.

Comment: at Michael:i was just about to follow your suggestion for a ListView when Damith made his suggestion, see my answer for the working version

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion of Damith (please upvote him) here the sollution, i publish the methods that gets executed when the user clicks the dataGridView with products, the corresponding  categories then are selected in the listbox.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
      listBox1.ClearSelected();
      if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1){
        List<CatProd> catProdLijst = catprod.Where(c => c.ProdID == 
          (int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ID"].Value).ToList();
        foreach (CatProd cp in catProdLijst) {
          for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++) {
            var category = listBox1.Items[i] as Categorie;
            if (category.ID == cp.CatID) {
              listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```