# How to change Listbox item color if it is present in another ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

I've requirement, its window forms application. I am new to C#, need your help to achieve below
SourceListbox and DestListbox and four buttons.
How to change SourceListbox item color to Green if it is added in another DestListBox with help of Copy Selected Button.
Again If i remove item from DestListbox, that item should go to Black color in SourceListbox.
Can somebody help me out please.

I am unable to insert picture for easy understanding

Please see link below
http://r4r.co.in/c1/01/tutorial/csharp/ListBox.shtml
exactly like above example. After items got added to DestListBox, what ever items matched in both source and Dest Listboxes should be in green color Text in both list boxes.

Below code giving the first item adding after green color,
but next items on selection only going green, which i don't want.

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        foreach (string str in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(str);                

            SourceListbox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;// OwnerDrawFixed;                
           SourceListbox.DrawItem += s_lstbxChannel_DrawItem;                
        }         

    } 



    void s_lstbxChannel_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        bool isItemSelected = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected);
        int itemIndex = e.Index;

        if (itemIndex >= 0 && itemIndex < listBox1.Items.Count)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;         // Background Color

            SolidBrush backgroundColorBrush = new SolidBrush((isItemSelected) ? Color.White : Color.White);

            g.FillRectangle(backgroundColorBrush, e.Bounds);         // Set text color

            string itemText = listBox1.Items[itemIndex].ToString();

            SolidBrush itemTextColorBrush = (isItemSelected) ? new SolidBrush(Color.Green) : new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            g.DrawString(itemText, e.Font, itemTextColorBrush, listBox1.GetItemRectangle(itemIndex).Location);// Clean up     

            backgroundColorBrush.Dispose();

            itemTextColorBrush.Dispose();
        }
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

Comment: If you add a *direct link* to your image, another user can edit it into your question. Your question as it stands is very unclear.. what is a SourceListbox and DestListbox and are you using winforms/wpf/asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Background color of a ListBox item (winforms)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3709452/4053168)

There you can see how to change the color of ListBoxItems. And with that you can do something like:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SourceListbox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        SourceListbox.DrawItem += SourceListbox_DrawItem;
    }

    //global brushes with ordinary/selected colors
    private SolidBrush reportsForegroundBrushSelected = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
    private SolidBrush reportsForegroundBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    private SolidBrush reportsBackgroundBrushSelected = new SolidBrush(Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight));
    private SolidBrush reportsBackgroundBrush1 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
    private SolidBrush reportsBackgroundBrush2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);

    //custom method to draw the items, don't forget to set DrawMode of the ListBox to OwnerDrawFixed
    private void SourceListbox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        bool selected = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected);

        int index = e.Index;
        if (index >= 0 && index < SourceListbox.Items.Count)
        {
            string text = SourceListbox.Items[index].ToString();
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            //background:
            SolidBrush backgroundBrush;
            if (selected)
                backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrushSelected;
            else if (DestListbox.Items.Contains(SourceListbox.Items[index]))
                backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrush2;
            else
                backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrush1;
            g.FillRectangle(backgroundBrush, e.Bounds);

            //text:*/
            SolidBrush foregroundBrush = (selected) ? reportsForegroundBrushSelected : reportsForegroundBrush;
            g.DrawString(text, e.Font, foregroundBrush, SourceListbox.GetItemRectangle(index).Location);
        }

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }

    private void buttonCopySelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (int idx in SourceListbox.SelectedIndices)
        {
            DestListbox.Items.Add(SourceListbox.Items[idx]);
        }
    }
```

Every item you copy from SourceListbox to DestListbox becomes green

Comment: I've tried above, not meeting my requirement. Just tried to explain better now my question, pl look at it

Comment: so you don't want the backgroundcolor set to green but the textcolor?  And you want it in both Listboxes, not only in the SourceListbox?  And after deleting the line in SourceListbox should look like before copying it?