# WinForms: Simplest way to change listbox text color on the fly?

Tags: c#, winforms, text, colors, listbox

Looking for a simple way to add color text (or bold text) to a listbox item (the solutions I've seen in Stackoverflow have seemed overly complicated for my needs).

I've been adding comments to my listbox via this code:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Test complete!");
```

This line is peppered throughout my code.  I'd love to be able to modify the occasional text with color such that a line like "Test complete!" shows up in green.

Is there a simple, on-the-fly solution to this?

Comment: No.  You have to setup the ListBox for owner draw and draw it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You can but takes a little a bit of [work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms) to setup, not really that complicated if you are just looking to setup the font color or font.

You have to add a handler to the DrawItem event.

```
this.listBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox1_DrawItem);
```

and here is a pretty simple handler that does what you are looking for.

```
void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Dictionary<string, object> props = (this.listBox1.Items[e.Index] as Dictionary<string, object>);
    SolidBrush backgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(props.ContainsKey("BackColor") ? (Color)props["BackColor"] : e.BackColor);
    SolidBrush foregroundBrush = new SolidBrush(props.ContainsKey("ForeColor") ? (Color)props["ForeColor"] : e.ForeColor);
    Font textFont = props.ContainsKey("Font") ? (Font)props["Font"] : e.Font;
    string text = props.ContainsKey("Text") ? (string)props["Text"] : string.Empty;
    RectangleF rectangle = new RectangleF(new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y), new SizeF(e.Bounds.Width, g.MeasureString(text, textFont).Height));

    g.FillRectangle(backgroundBrush, rectangle);
    g.DrawString(text, textFont, foregroundBrush, rectangle);

    backgroundBrush.Dispose();
    foregroundBrush.Dispose();
    g.Dispose();
}
```

and then to add items to the ListBox you can do this.

```
this.listBox1.Items.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Text", "Something, something"},
                                                         { "BackColor", Color.Red },
                                                         { "ForeColor", Color.Green}});
this.listBox1.Items.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Text", "darkside!!" },
                                                         { "BackColor", Color.Blue },
                                                         { "ForeColor", Color.Green },
                                                         { "Font", new Font(new Font("Arial", 9), FontStyle.Bold) } });
```

Fairly simple I think.

[image: Tada]

Comment: You are adding a new textbox for every item in the listbox.  Yikes.  What if the user has 10,000 items?  Ouch.  Dispose your brushes, by the way.

Comment: @LarsTech, you are right using a textbox is overkill and a custom class that contains those properties is the way to go, I guess I made it a bit too simple.

Comment: Half tempted to upvote on grounds of your example text alone.

Comment: The end goal for the picture was of course to use my honeyed words to illicit upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do with without drawing the items in the `ListBox` yourself. However, this isn't hard to accomplish with code. A trivial implementation that assumes the items aren't removed/reordered in the list box involves just keeping a dictionary mapping an index to a color and then drawing it with something like this:

```
private void ListBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var isItemSelected = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected);

    Color foreColor;
    if (!this.mColorsByIndex.TryGetValue(e.Index, out foreColor))
    {
        foreColor = isItemSelected ? SystemColors.HighlightText : this.mListBox.ForeColor;
    }

    var backColor = isItemSelected ? SystemColors.Highlight : this.mListBox.BackColor;
    using (var backBrush = new SolidBrush(backColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backBrush, e.Bounds);
    }

    var item = this.mListBox.Items[e.Index];
    var itemText = this.mListBox.GetItemText(item);
    const TextFormatFlags formatFlags = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, itemText, e.Font, e.Bounds, foreColor, formatFlags);
}
```

In terms of custom drawing in `WinForms`, this is almost as simple as it gets.

Note that `ListBox.Items.Add` returns the index of the item you added.

Keeping up with the color associations gets a little harder if you remove/change/reorder items in the `ListBox`, but that complicates tracking the color associations, not the drawing itself.