# change color item listbox c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I have created a `ListBox` to which I add elements during code compilation. and I want to record its color when adding one element (so that each added element has a different color)

```
listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("Місце {0} | В роботі з {1} | ({2} хв)", temp[7].Substring(6, 4), temp[8].Substring(11, 5), rezult));   `
```

I tried everywhere possible to embed this change

```
BackColor = Color.Yellow;ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
```

I am working with listbox because I have seen so many answers about `ListView`.

Comment: Assuming WinForms, you can't set the colour of an individual item via simple properties. You will need to owner-draw the items. Look at the [`DrawMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property and [`DrawItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) event of the control .

Comment: As @jmcilhinney says, it requires a little bit of work. Have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173517/winforms-simplest-way-to-change-listbox-text-color-on-the-fly)

Comment: For example: [How to add multiline Text to a ListBox item?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60589434/7444103). You can set the text Color and the background color of selected and non selected items to whatever you want. You can determine what color to use based on whatever condition you define. Could be a tag or similar, part of text. You can replace it while drawing an item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the listbox DrawMode to either OwnerDrawFixed or OwnerDrawVariable and set this as  the DrawItem event handler:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e){
    if(e.Index == 1) e.DrawBackground(); //use e.Index to see if we want to highlight the item
    else e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), e.Bounds); //This does the same thing as e.DrawBackground but with a custom color
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    if(e.Index < 0) return;
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, (string)listBox1.Items[e.Index], listBox1.Font, e.Bounds, listBox1.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left);
}
```

Comment: I just amended the item text in the call to DrawText if you were wondering about that.

Comment: yes i noticed)
now I'm thinking how to screw it into my program, I'm still a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

Well, best idea I have is to not use list box, but **flowLayoutPanel** and add usercontrols where you will have labels.

`flowLayoutPanel` works as list of controls which you can scroll, so we will just create a `usercontrol`, where we will put label and change the `usercontrol` background
Don't forget to turn on the `AutoScroll` feature to `flowLayoutPanel`, otherwise the scroll bar wont work and wont even show up.

If you want to be able to be clickable just add to the label click event.

```
 public void CreateItem(Color OurColor, string TextToShow)
        {
    
    
            Label OurText = new Label()
            {
                Text = "TextToShow",
                Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8f),
                Location = new Point(0, 0),
                AutoSize = true,
    
            };
    
            UserControl OurUserControl = new UserControl();
    
            OurUserControl.Size = new Size((int)((double)flowLayoutPanel1.Width * 0.9) , OurText.Font.Height);
    
            OurUserControl.BackColor = OurColor;
            OurUserControl.Controls.Add(OurText);
    
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(OurUserControl);
            
            
        }
```

Comment: quite a good idea in the future I will keep in mind. But for now it's easier for me to understand the listbox. Thank you for your help