# WindowsForm listbox draw item

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, listbox

I am trying to change the color of a speicifc item in the list box. This is the code that I am using. The problem is that all the items in the listbox get the same color and the same text. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     lbPossibleChildren.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
     lbPossibleChildren.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(lbDraw);
 }
 private void lbDraw(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
 {
     e.DrawBackground();
     Graphics g = e.Graphics;
     g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Orange), e.Bounds);
     g.DrawString(lbPossibleChildren.Items[3].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
     e.DrawFocusRectangle();
 }
```

[image: ScreenShot of the result]

Comment: You are drawing all items the same way, also using the same text.

Comment: I thought so. How can I switch to drawing only one of them?

Comment: Can you use listview instead of using ListBox?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3709452/1633308) has some good example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replece your `listbox` to `listview` it allow to change items color.

```
listView1.Items[1].BackColor = Color.Green;
```