# Changing listbox string text depending

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm not exactly sure the best way to do this, i am trying to change the colour of the font in my listbox green (ok) or red (if there was an exception of some kind, the basic code in the try / catch)

```
try {
    Parallel.ForEach(list, po,  url =>
    {
        try {
            getRequest(url, txtBoxTargetURL.Text);
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { listBoxMain.Items.Add($"Executed - [{txtBoxRequestAmount.Text}] - {url}"); }));
            po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { listBoxMain.Items.Add($"Exception during processing: {url} - {ex.Message}"); }));
        }
    });
```

So the exception text which is added should all be red, and the strings above the exception will all be green, the strings are dynamic so i can't even say if string == "this word" then turn green for example, i know from reading i need to change the draw mode and place code in:

```
private void listBoxMain_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms

Comment: You could use `ListView` instead, and set `BackgroundColor` on each item. Or you can use `DrawItem` with `ListBox` as you suggest. Instead of adding strings directly, make a new class which contains a string property and a color property. Add instances of this class to the list instead of strings, and use the properties to draw each item in your custom `DrawItem` method.